# convert memory address to int

Tags: c++, readprocessmemory

I am trying to read memory addresses from an executable running in memory, and then use those memory addresses to walk the PE structure.

I am having trouble because I'm unsure how to convert a 4 byte char array to it's int equivalent.

Here is my code so far:

```
char buffer[4];
int e_lfanew = 60;

if(!ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (me32.modBaseAddr + e_lfanew), buffer, 4, NULL))
{
    printf("ReadProcessMemory @ %x Failed (%d)\n", me32.modBaseAddr, GetLastError());
}
```

The address i'm reading in, in this case 0xE0000000, is the offset of the PE Header.  I want to take the memory address I just read and use it as an offset to read from process memory again, but I cannot figure out how to convert it to an int properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is safer to use `size_t` type instead of `int` type. `int` is always 32-bit long, regardless of your target architecture (32 or 64 bit). Memory addresses on 64-bit machines, however, are 64-bit long. `size_t` size correctly adjusts to that.

Comment: It's actually better to use an integer pointer data type, like `(u)intptr_t` (or `ptrdiff_t` for differences between pointers) instead of `size_t`, which is not really for pointers, but for sizes.

Comment: Considering the call to `ReadProcessMemory`, I'd advise `UINT_PTR` - match Win32 functions with Win32 types.

Answer (score 3):

```
 buffer[0]        | 
(buffer[1] <<  8) |
(buffer[2] << 16) |
(buffer[3] << 24)
```

or the other way around, depending on whether your high-order byte is buffer[0] or buffer[3]

Answer (score 0):

```
int MemoryBufferToInt(char* buffer, int buffer_size) {
   int result;
   assert(buffer_size == sizeof(result));
   memcpy(&result, &buffer[0], sizeof(result));
   return result;
}
```

The code above assumes that this buffer was obtained from the process, so that the byte order of the memory buffer is the same as the byte order of a regular int on your platform. Otherwise, you can easily contruct the integer for a specific byte order if you know what the byte order of the buffer is.

NOTE that you could just use `static_cast<char*>(&result)` in place of your buffer as the parameter to the function that retrieves the buffer contents.